# Why vector length SIMD code is slower than plain C

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, sse, simd, microbenchmark

Why is my SIMD vector4 length function 3x slower than a naive vector length method?

SIMD vector4 length function:

```c
__extern_always_inline float vec4_len(const float *v) {
    __m128 vec1 = _mm_load_ps(v);
    __m128 xmm1 = _mm_mul_ps(vec1, vec1);
    __m128 xmm2 = _mm_hadd_ps(xmm1, xmm1);
    __m128 xmm3 = _mm_hadd_ps(xmm2, xmm2);
    return sqrtf(_mm_cvtss_f32(xmm3));
}
```

Naive implementation:

```c
sqrtf(V[0] * V[0] + V[1] * V[1] + V[2] * V[2] + V[3] * V[3])
```

The SIMD version took 16110ms to iterate 1000000000 times. The naive version was ~3 times faster, it takes only 4746ms.

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

static float vec4_len(const float *v) {
    __m128 vec1 = _mm_load_ps(v);
    __m128 xmm1 = _mm_mul_ps(vec1, vec1);
    __m128 xmm2 = _mm_hadd_ps(xmm1, xmm1);
    __m128 xmm3 = _mm_hadd_ps(xmm2, xmm2);
    return sqrtf(_mm_cvtss_f32(xmm3));
}

int main() {
    float A[4] __attribute__((aligned(16))) = {3, 4, 0, 0};

    struct timespec t0 = {};
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t0);

    double sum_len = 0;
    for (uint64_t k = 0; k < 1000000000; ++k) {
        A[3] = k;
        sum_len += vec4_len(A);
//        sum_len += sqrtf(A[0] * A[0] + A[1] * A[1] + A[2] * A[2] + A[3] * A[3]);
    }
    struct timespec t1 = {};
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t1);

    fprintf(stdout, "%f\n", sum_len);

    fprintf(stdout, "%ldms\n", (((t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) * 1000000000) + (t1.tv_nsec - t0.tv_nsec)) / 1000000);

    return 0;
}
```

I run with the following command on an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU. First with the `vec4_len` version then with the plain C.

I compile with GCC (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -msse -msse3 sse.c -lm && ./a.out
```

SSE version output:

```
499999999500000128.000000
13458ms
```

Plain C version output:

```
499999999500000128.000000
4441ms
```

Comment: `haddps` is pretty bad, a factor of 3 still sounds like a lot though, is there anything interesting in the disassembly?

Comment: How did you benchmark this?  Are you sure the scalar version wasn't hoisting some of the work?  What compiler / version on what hardware, as well as what was the surrounding code that this inlined into?  Also, since you have your value in a `__m128i`, you can avoid the stupid set-errno-on-NaN behaviour for `sqrtf()` by using `_mm_sqrt_ss`, so you don't have to compile with `-fno-math-errno`

Comment: Compiler version required. [Mcve] required. Godbolt links nice.

Comment: What is your actual use-case? Occasionally, compute the norm of single vectors, or compute the norms of a sequence of vectors? Are you able to re-organize your data ([SoA vs AoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOS_and_SOA))?

Comment: Looks like the compile is better in optimizing then you are [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MBeAlX). Your function looks faster for arbitrary data (the assembly is way shorter), but your method of measuring execution speed is kind-of invalid, the compiler optimizes the loop better. You need to use two function and tell the compiler about side effects. Ex use `__attribute__((__noinline__))`, like in [something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/7vsPx-).

Comment: @KamilCuk: But the asm uses `haddps` which is garbage, especially for Sandybridge-family.  It costs 2 shuffle uops + 1 vertical-add uop, and SnB-family has 1-per-clock shuffle uop throughput.  (Port 5).  Until IceLake adds a 2nd shuffle unit on another port.  This is one of those cases where shorter asm isn't always better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most obvious problem is using an inefficient dot-product (with `haddps` which costs 2x shuffle uops + 1x add uop) instead of shuffle + add.  See [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86) for what to do after `_mm_mul_ps` that doesn't suck as much.  But still this is just not something x86 can do very efficiently.

**But anyway, the real problem is your benchmark loop.**

`A[3] = k;` and then using `_mm_load_ps(A)` creates **a store-forwarding stall**, if it compiles naively instead of to a vector shuffle.  A store + reload can be efficiently forwarded with ~5 cycles of latency if the load only loads data from a single store instruction, and no data outside that.  Otherwise it has to do a slower scan of the whole store buffer to assemble bytes.  This adds about 10 cycles of latency to the store-forwarding.

I'm not sure how much impact this has on throughput, but could be enough to stop out-of-order exec from overlapping enough loop iterations to hide the latency and only bottleneck on `sqrtss` shuffle throughput.

(Your Coffee Lake CPU has 1 per 3 cycle `sqrtss` throughput, so surprisingly SQRT throughput is *not* your bottleneck.<sup>1</sup>  Instead it will be shuffle throughput or something else.)

See [Agner Fog's](https://agner.org/optimize/) microarch guide and/or optimization manual.

- [What does "store-buffer forwarding" mean in the Intel developer's manual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176599/what-does-store-buffer-forwarding-mean-in-the-intel-developers-manual)
- [How does store to load forwarding happens in case of unaligned memory access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210733/how-does-store-to-load-forwarding-happens-in-case-of-unaligned-memory-access)
- [Can modern x86 implementations store-forward from more than one prior store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135766/can-modern-x86-implementations-store-forward-from-more-than-one-prior-store)
- [Why would a compiler generate this assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679131/why-would-a-compiler-generate-this-assembly/16681018#16681018) quotes Intel's optimization manual re: store forwarding.  (In that question, and old gcc version stored the 2 dword halves of an 8-byte struct separately, then copied the struct with a qword load/store.  Super braindead.)

---

Plus you're biasing this even more against SSE by **letting the compiler hoist the computation of `V[0] * V[0] + V[1] * V[1] + V[2] * V[2]` out of the loop**.

That part of the expression is loop-invariant, so the compiler only has to do `(float)k` squared, add, and a scalar sqrt every loop iteration.  (And convert that to `double` to add to your accumulator).

(@StaceyGirl's deleted answer pointed this out; looking over the code of the inner loops in it was a great start on writing this answer.)

---

### Extra inefficiency in A[3] = k in the vector version

GCC9.1's inner loop from [Kamil's Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/MBeAlX) looks terrible, and seems to include a loop-carried store/reload to merge a new `A[3]` into the 8-byte `A[2..3]` pair, further limiting the CPU's ability to overlap multiple iterations.

I'm not sure why gcc thought this was a good idea.  It would maybe help on CPUs that split vector loads into 8-byte halves (like Pentium M or Bobcat) to avoid store-forwarding stalls.  But that's not a sane tuning for "generic" modern x86-64 CPUs.

```
.L18:
        pxor    xmm4, xmm4
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]     ; reload A[2..3]
        cvtsi2ss        xmm4, rbx
        mov     edx, edx                   ; truncate RDX to 32-bit
        movd    eax, xmm4                  ; float bit-pattern of (float)k
        sal     rax, 32
        or      rdx, rax                   ; merge the float bit-pattern into A[3]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rdx     ; store A[2..3] again

        movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsp]    ; vector load: store-forwarding stall
        mulps   xmm0, xmm0
        haddps  xmm0, xmm0
        haddps  xmm0, xmm0
        ucomiss xmm3, xmm0
        movaps  xmm1, xmm0
        sqrtss  xmm1, xmm1
        ja      .L21             ; call sqrtf to set errno if needed; flags set by ucomiss.
.L17:

        add     rbx, 1
        cvtss2sd        xmm1, xmm1
        addsd   xmm2, xmm1            ; total += (double)sqrtf
        cmp     rbx, 1000000000
        jne     .L18                ; }while(k<1000000000);
```

This insanity isn't present in the scalar version.

Either way, gcc did manage to avoid the inefficiency of a full `uint64_t` -> `float` conversion (which x86 doesn't have in hardware until AVX512).  It was presumably able to prove that using a signed 64-bit -> float conversion would always work because the high bit can't be set.

---

**Footnote 1**:  But `sqrtps` has the same 1 per 3 cycle throughput as scalar, so you're only getting 1/4 of your CPU's sqrt throughput capability by doing 1 vector at a time horizontally, instead of doing 4 lengths for 4 vectors in parallel.